# How to get a HCRYPTKEY from X.509 certificate?

Tags: winapi, certificate, smartcard, cryptoapi

The certificate is obtained from a smart card via the BSI API (`gscBsiPkiGetCertificate`) and I'm trying to get the key handle to its public/private key pair to perform asymmetric crypto operations using the CryptoAPI's `CryptEncrypt` and `CryptDecrypt` functions.

### What I've Tried

`gscBsiPkiGetCertificate` returns the raw certificate data in hex encoded form and I was able to decode it and successfully call `CertCreateCertificateContext` to get the `CERT_CONTEXT` structure. With this `CERT_CONTEXT`, I had tried `CertGetCertificateContextProperty` with parameters

- `CERT_KEY_CONTEXT_PROP_ID`
- `CERT_KEY_PROV_HANDLE_PROP_ID`
- `CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID`
- `CERT_HCRYPTPROV_OR_NCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE_PROP_ID`
- `CERT_HCRYPTPROV_TRANSFER_PROP_ID`

However all of them returned `CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND`. I had also tried `GetCryptProvFromCert` in hope of getting the certificate container handle, which would then allow me to get the key handle via `CryptGetUserKey`. However `GetCryptProvFromCert` failed with error `CRYPT_E_NO_KEY_PROPERTY`.

I am currently using pure CryptoAPI as a workaround: `CryptAcquireContext` to access card -> `CryptGetProvParam` to enumerate certificate containers -> `CryptAcquireContext` to access container -> `CryptGetUserKey` to get key handle. This is far from ideal since I've to interate through the containers to find the required certificate. `gscBsiPkiGetCertificate` allows me to specify an AID value to get the certificate directly.

I had also tried using `CryptEncryptMessage` which takes a `PCCERT_CONTEXT` directly and thus avoiding the need for the `HCRYPTKEY`. However, trying with algorithm identifiers `szOID_RSA`, `szOID_RSA_ENCRPT`, and `szOID_RSA_DH` all returned `CRYPT_E_UNKNOWN_ALGO`. I'm quite sure the certificate supports RSA encryption since calling `CryptGetKeyParam` with `KP_ALGID` on the key handle obtained through CryptoAPI returns me `CALG_RSA_KEYX`

### Bonus Challenge

I am using BSI API to access both data and certificate containers within the card. I would like to avoid the workaround as I want to standardise all smart card operations to use only BSI or CryptoAPI. If it's impossible for me to get the key handle using BSI API, I would then like know how to use CryptoAPI to access the data containers. `CryptGetProvParam` only enumerates the certificate containers.

Comment: certificate internally containing only public key. so you can extract it and use for encrypt data only (or check signature). private key is stored by provider separate. so you need have relationship between certificate and provider. CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID and other properties also of course not stored in certificate, but in memory structs related to CERT_CONTEXT - result of CertGetCertificateContextProperty very depended from how you got CERT_CONTEXT. if you got it from store (say CertFindCertificateInStore) you can get some of this properties.

Comment: if you create CERT_CONTEXT from raw data (CertCreateCertificateContext) - no this properties in context

Comment: What keeps you from using `gscBsiPkiCompute()`? I mean, if you have to access `gscBsiPkiGetCertificate` you might as well also access other functions within the API, right? Otherwise you may have to write your own CSP (cryptographic service provider) / plugin for CryptoAPI.

Comment: @RbMm thanks for the clarification. May I know how did you learn about these details?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes unfortunately the BSI API only seems to support the BSI_RSA_NO_PAD algorithm, which I presume is RSA with no padding. I require RSA with padding.

Comment: So add the padding first. It should be in the Mono implementation somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like that 
1) you get the certificate context e.g. 
pSignerCertContext = CertFindCertificateInStore(hCertStore, PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING | X509_ASN_ENCODING, 0, CERT_FIND_HASH, &hashBlob, NULL)

2) you get a handle to crypt provider e.g. :
CryptAcquireContext(&hProv, strContainer.c_str(), strProvider.c_str(), PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_SILENT)

3) You associate the certificate context with the crypt provider e.g. 
CertSetCertificateContextProperty(pSignerCertContext, CERT_SET_KEY_PROV_HANDLE_PROP_ID, 0, &hProv)

4) after this you can use either CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey or CryptGetUserKey